# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{nf^{(n)}}(x)$ where $xf(x)=e^x-1$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Given that $xf(x)=e^x-1$ calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}{nf^{(n)}}(x)$.

I have try to figure the $n$th derivative of the function but it looks messy. The only useful recurrence I found is this one:
$$nf^{(n-1)}(x)+xf^{(n)}(x)=e^x$$

Comment: Are you familiar with [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)? I feel like applying a limit procedure to that could help with this problem.

Comment: That recurrence would be more useful if you differentiated it one more time, I think. Then you would have a term $n f^{(n)}(x)$ as desired. (By the way note that at 0 this problem is easy.)

Comment: @Zach466920 No idea how L'Hopital will be useful in this case.

Comment: @Ian I looked at what you mentioned nothing came out.

Comment: @Ian the function isn't well defined at 0. I assume $f(0)=1$ for continuity though.

Comment: @motoras Are you sure? Assuming your given recurrence is correct (I didn't check it) $n f^{(n)}(x) + f^{(n)}(x) + x f^{(n)}(x) = e^x$. Assuming the desired limit exists and $x$ is held fixed then the second and third terms vanish as $n \to \infty$. I think this gives what you want.

Comment: @Ian why you think they vanish? They are some expressions in $x$.

Comment: Because if $f^{(n)}$ does not go zero then $n f^{(n)}$ cannot converge.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: @Ian The recurrence relation is indeed correct. Simple induction problem, or integrating by parts from my solution.

Comment: @Ian I think one of your $^{(n)}$ should be $^{(n+1)}$.

Comment: @ClementC. You are right though everything goes through the same way.

Comment: @Ian Yes. I've added a CW answer before realizing this was the same approach as in your comment (note that one doesn't need to differentiate more: this is exactly then the recurrence relation found by the OP, but at $n+1$ instead of $n$). I can't see how to argue that $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ does converge to $0$ (wrt $n\to\infty$), however, which is necessary to conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Partial solution: feel free to edit to add the last missing piece (it's a Community Wiki answer).**

*I've had to refrain from using the power series for $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$, namely $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$, to answer. This is tempting, though, and I encourage you to try: in any case, this lets one show very easily that $$n f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{n}{n+1} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1.$$*

Start with your recurrence relation, specifically
$$
n f^{(n-1)}(x)+xf^{(n)}(x)=e^x\tag{for all $x$}
$$
which is easy to prove by induction. Switching indices, we get that for $n\geq 1$
$$
(n+1) f^{(n)}(x)+xf^{(n+1)}(x)=e^x\tag{for all $x$}
$$
and therefore
$$
n f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n}{n+1}\left( e^x - xf^{(n+1)}(x) \right)\tag{for all $x$}
$$
**If** we knew that, for any fixed $x_0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{(n)}(x_0) = 0$, we'd then be done: indeed, then the RHS of the above relation would converge to $1\cdot (e^{x_0}-0)$, yielding that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n f^{(n)}(x) = e^x
$$
for any fixed $x$. We don't know that, however.

Comment: If one continues as in the now deleted answer @ajotatxe then one gets after cancellations that $$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-n}}{(k-n)!\cdot (k+1)}=[k-n=m]=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{m!\cdot (m+n+1)}$$ which can be estimated as $|f^{(n)}(x)|\le \frac{1}{n+1}e^{|x|}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 18):

Hint:

$$f(x)=\int_0^1e^{xt}~\mathrm dt $$

Thus,

\begin{align}f^{(n)}(x)&=\int_0^1t^ne^{xt}~\mathrm dt\\&=\frac{e^x}{n+1}-x\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}e^{xt}~\mathrm dt\end{align}

where

$$0\le\left|\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}e^{xt}~\mathrm dt\right|\le\int_0^1\frac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}e^{|x|}~\mathrm dt=\frac{e^{|x|}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

Comment: Well played sir

Comment: I do believe that the problem was asked to students before they learn integration...

Comment: @motors I have seen no evidence that this is the case.

Comment: Likewise, answers may be geared towards a wider audience than only the OP.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt can you please detail this answer.  I don't know hot to continue it..

Comment: @motoras can you take the nth derivative?

Comment: @motoras I've added more details upon your request.

Comment: Thank you, anyway I still do not get how you end up with the formula  for $f^{(n)}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64848/discussion-between-motoras-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Very nice! (+1) Is it just a matter of experience or is there a specific aspect which leads to this approach?

Comment: @MarkusScheuer experience. I picked up from Jack D'Aurizio that finding the integral form of certain things can be very useful

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I see. Many thanks for your reply.